# Handle exception with a failed tcp connection in c# .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, tcp

i'm trying to handle the exception of a failed tcp connection, but i don't know how exactly do it. I need it when it's impossible to connect to the server and i would a simple Message box that says the it's impossible to contact the server and than the program return to the main form.

```
 public Connessione(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

            }

            catch
            {
                show the message box and go back to the main form

            }

        }
```

this is the part of the code. i would ask you also a good guide about how to handle exception. thank you so much!!

Comment: What have you already triedor what do you expect to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the catch statement you can get the exception thrown like this (or anything similar):

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Also, if you do not catch the exception (or throw a new one), any code calling the *Connessione* method can catch the exception like this:

```
void FirstMethod()
{
  try
  {
    Connessione("google.com", 80);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to server: " + ex.Message);
  }
}

public void Connessione(string hostname, int port)
{
  TcpClient tcpSocket = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
  // ... Doing things with tcpSocket
}
```

---

This is a great article going through how exceptions work and how to use them properly:

https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com%2F

Comment: i used the second method, it's perfect. Also the guide is very clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GiulioAndini Happy to help! :D